# How to filter tree structure?

Tags: c#, tree

I have a tree of objects `MyNode`:

```
public class MyNode
{
   public int Type { get; set; }
   public List<MyNode> Children { get; set; }
}

MyNode myRootNode;
// initializing a tree structure
```

So I need to remove all nodes except

1. Nodes that have `Type` property is equal to `int myType`
2. Nodes that contains in their child nodes at any level nodes with `Type` property is equal to `int myType`

My way:

```
bool Filter(MyNode node, MyNode parentNode, int type)
{
   bool isFound = false;

   if (node.Type == type)
      isFound = true; // There's type

   foreach (MyNode child in node.Children)
   {
      if (FilterTree(child, node, type))
          isFound = true; // There is child node who has this type
   }

   // If there aren't this type neither any of its children has it
   if (!isFound)
   {
      parentNode.Children.Remove(node);
   }

   return isFound;
}
```

I've got an exeption: `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` I think that's because I deleting elements in the list. Is there a way to do it the right way ? Or what am I donig wrong ?

Comment: Do you actually need to modify initial collection of just filter (select items satisfying criteria)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the root node is always retained, you can remove the children in the mathod, not the node itself.

```
bool Filter(MyNode node,int type)
{
//remove children
foreach(MyNode child in node.Children.Where(c=>!Filter(c, type)).ToArray())
    node.Children.Remove(child);
//return if should be retained
return node.Type==type || node.Children.Count>0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Linq comes to rescue you:

```
public static void RemoveNodesRecursive(this MyNode node, Predicate<MyNode> predicate)
{
    node.Children.RemoveAll(predicate);
    foreach (var n in node.Children)
    {
        RemoveNodes(n);
    }
}
```

and then start with the root node:

```
myRootNode.RemoveNodesRecursive(n => n.node.Type == myType)
```